# Choosing my most preferred card from a set of n cards.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I have $n$ cards, however, I like only 1 card the most out of all the $n$ cards and that card is my favourite. I consider the cards one by one, giving each an integer score, where the higher the score means the more I like that card. There are no ties in scores. The game is such that once I am done considering the $k^{th}$ card I lose the opportunity to select it as my favourite card forever. Suppose the candidates are considered in random order, chosen uniformly at random from all $n!$ possible orderings.

Current plan: consider the first $m$ cards, find the max score among them and then discard them. After the $m^{th}$ card, choose the first card who receives a higher score than the maximum from $m$ cards to be the favourite.

Let $E$ be the event that I choose my most preferred card as my favourite. Let $E_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ card is the most preferred and i choose it as my favourite. Find Pr[$E_i$] and show that Pr[$E_i$] = $\frac{m}{n} \sum_{j=m+1}^{n}\frac{1}{j-1}$

I have no idea how to begin solving this sum. Any intuition would be nice.

Comment: This is known as the [Secretary Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem)

Comment: That series is  the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{k}$ starting on $k=m$ and finishing in $k=n-1$. I don´t know if this will help you

Comment: @lulu could you explain the math under the 'Deriving the optimal policy' section

Comment: It's pretty literal.  The strategy is "Look passively at the first $r-1$ applicants. Then, after that, pick the first one that is better that all the ones you saw. " In order for this to work you need the best applicant to come after the first $r-1$ and, moreover, the best applicant must come first amongst all the applicants after the first $r-1$ which are better than all the first $r-1$.  The article simply writes all this out carefully.

Comment: For instance:  if the second best is amongst the first $r-1$ but the best is not, then this strategy works perfectly.  If the third best is amongst the first $r-1$ but neither the best nor the second best is, then the strategy works with probability $\frac 12$. And so on.

Comment: @lulu what I am confused by is that big | in the third line.  Is that an OR? or am i misreading it? The rest of it is straightforward like you said.

Comment: That just means "conditioned on", as part of a conditional probability.  Thus $P(A\,|\,B)$ means "the probability of $A$ conditioned on $B$".